# Fill structure with data in array

Tags: c, struct, arm, malloc

I have an array with raw data with the size of `64 bytes`

```
#define SIZE_OF_LIMITS_STRUCTURE 64
uint32_t *set_limits = (uint32_t *)malloc(SIZE_OF_LIMITS_STRUCTURE);
```

I fill This array with actual data from memory.

---

And I have a structure (size of the structure is `64 bytes`)

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t A
    uint8_t B
    uint8_t C
    uint8_t D
    uint8_t E
    uint8_t F
    uint8_t G
    uint8_t H
    uint16_t I
    uint16_t J
    uint16_t K
    uint16_t L
    uint16_t M
    uint16_t N
    uint16_t O
    uint16_t P
    uint16_t Q
    uint16_t R
    uint16_t S
    uint16_t T
    uint16_t U
    uint16_t V
    uint16_t W
    uint16_t X
    uint16_t Y
    uint16_t Z
    uint16_t AA
    uint16_t BB
    uint16_t CC
    uint16_t DD
    uint16_t EE
    uint16_t FF
    uint16_t GG
    uint16_t HH
    uint16_t II
    uint16_t JJ
} __attribute__ ((packed)) Limits,  *Plimits;
```

And I need to update value in this structure with data in the array:

```
LimitySenzoru = (Plimits)set_limits;
```

And the function is wrong. And I don't know why.

---

Here is the complete function to fill structure:

```
volatile Plimits LimitySenzoru = NULL;

void update_structure(void)
{
    uint32_t *set_limits = (uint32_t *)malloc(SIZE_OF_LIMITS_STRUCTURE);
    uint32_t addr = ADDRESS_OF_LIMITS_IN_MEM;
    uint32_t test[] = {0};

    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_LIMITS_STRUCTURE/4; ++i)
    {
        Read_from_memory_32(addr, test); //read datas from memory to array
        set_limits[i] = test[0];
        addr += 4;
    }

    /* fill structure by datas */
    LimitySenzoru = (Plimits)set_limits;

    /* free memory */
    free(set_limits);
}
```

When I fill the structure, with data and print it:

```
datas = [4, 8, 18, 21, 0, 5, 30, 31, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 92, 94, 99, 101, 104, 109, 113, 119, 125, 126, 128, 129, 132, 134, 135, 137, 138, 141, 150, 151, 153, 159, 161, 167, 169, 170, 178, 179, 183, 187, 195, 197, 204, 206, 207, 208, 213, 218, 223, 230, 240, 248]
```

`The first 4 values (A, B, C, D)` are `0`.
When I disable `free`, the structure filling is completed, but it doesn't refresh value.

Any idea, how to fill structure with raw datas?

Comment: This design looks wrong to me, use an array instead of individual fields.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: defining the size of a structure to a constant number seems a bad idea anyways. But then, this whole code just leaves a big question mark here.

Comment: BTW: If you have an array with only 1 element, you probably don't need an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a dangling pointer:

```
/* fill structure by datas */
LimitySenzoru = (Plimits)set_limits;
/* free memory */
free(set_limits);
```

After this youf global variable `LimitySenzoru` points to the memory location that was freed. After freeing you are not allowed to access this memory location any longer. Otherwise you have *undefined behaviour*.

From the comment you seem to mix some concepts.

You do *not* fill any data into any struct. You simply copy a pointer. Nothing else.
You either need to keep the allocated memory and not `free` it or you need to allocate memory for `LimitySenzoru` and do some `memcpy` to fill data from one struct into the other.

Comment: And how to use memcpy to copy raw data in array to structure? I tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Just as with every other data object: `memcpy(LimitySenzoru, set_limits, sizeof(*LimitySenzoru));` Of course you mustn't forget to provide memory for `LimitySenzoru` to point to.

Comment: This solution is working fine: `memcpy(LimitySenzoru, set_limits, sizeof(*LimitySenzoru));`. When I tried it, I forgot on * in sizeof(*LimitySenzoru)

Comment: So in ARM it is working fine. But I tried implenet in online compiler, and I have mistake: [link](https://onlinegdb.com/BkeuV0SVQ) Any idea, what is wrong?

Comment: Yes. Read my comment above. "Of course you mustn't forget..." No one likes `NULL`pointers.